# upper bound of n-derivative of sigmoid function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $\sigma(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ be the sigmoid function, and $\sigma^{(n)}(x)$ be its n-derivative, for any $x\in [-1/2,1/2]$, any $n\geq 1$, is it true that $|\frac{\sigma^{(n)}(x)}{n!}|\leq C$? C is a constant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a way to solve this problem, which also uses Leibniz rule, but in a tricky way. Note that $\sigma^{(1)}=\sigma(1-\sigma)$, therefore, $\sigma^{(n+1)}=(\sigma(1-\sigma))^{(n)}=\sum_{k}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\sigma^{(k)}(1-\sigma)^{(n-k)}$. Now do induction, suppose $|\sigma^{(k)}|\leq k!$, we can easily get the final result.

Comment: It is an elegant solution.